# Android z-order management of SurfaceView using SDK

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have two SurfaceView in my application which are stacked over each other. I want to swap them to swap their z-order so that background SurfaceView can become front and front SurfaceView goes to background. They both are used for Video Playback.

I am using Android API 15 version for ICS.

Is there any method in Android SDK which will allow me to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

A really easy way to get this to happen is to put both your surface views into the same ViewGroup. When you want the one in the back to go to the front, remove it from the ViewGroup, then re-add it to the ViewGroup. This should cause the order to swap.